# table to pdf in mvc using jspdf (or similar)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, jspdf

I have a table in an mvc view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Trasaction Date</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Company Name</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Store Name</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Loan #</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Customer Name</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Payment Amount</span>
        </th>
        <th>Tender Type</th>
        <th>
            <span>Transaction Ref</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>IP Address</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Store ID</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>Originating User</span>
        </th>
        <th></th> 
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Transaction_Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company_Master.Company_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Loc_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account_Loan_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer_First_Name) </span><span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer_Last_Name)</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tender_Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginatedVia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Loc_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Inserted_By)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="btndeletediv">
                    <input type="button" id="@(item.Payment_ID)" value="Print" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and this table looks like ![this]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ5j0.png

When I click on a pdfexport button I want to display the same table in a pdf with css.

I have tried using iTextSharp but with no luck. How can I use jspdf where I want to pass a table id (or anything similar).

I've tried searching but couldn't find any one exporting a table to a pdf.

Thanks in advance